# Mapping values at the top level and a single value from a nested object

Tags: curl, jira, jq

I'm attempting to do this with a jira issue and a custom field and it's proving to be quite difficult.

For conciseness lets say that the below is what I've received:

```
"expand": "editmeta,renderedFields,transitions,changelog,operations",
"id": "59378",
"self": "https://myjirainstance.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/59378",
"key": "AB-12345",
"fields":
  {
    "type": "Bug",
    "typeid": "19",
    "status": "Backlog",
    "summary": "I'm a big bad bug",
    "closedDate": null,
    "customfield_10170":[{"self":"http://address/1938","value":"Critical","id":"10404"}]
  },
```

I've previously mapped all the other fields like so

```
curl to jira | jq '.["issues"] | 
   map({
    key: .key, 
    type: .fields.issuetype.name, 
    typeid: .fields.issuetype.id, 
    status: .fields.status.name, 
    summary: .fields.summary, 
    closedDate: .fields.resolutiondate, 
    flag: .fields.customfield_10170["value"]})'
    >  output/json/FullIssueList.json
```

But adding that last line in order to get `value` as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562424/jq-nested-object-extract-top-level-id-and-lift-a-value-from-internal-object) results in the entire object being excluded from the output file.

any ideas?

Comment: Wait a minute, where's this `fields` property and others coming from? That's not what appears in the data. Can you post a more complete example of the data?

Comment: @JeffMercado, sure thing, I'll update the post.

Comment: @JeffMercado, I got it. Thanks for making me re-evaluate what I had. I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer,

The original and incorrect attempt looks like this:

```
curl to jira | jq '.["issues"] | 
   map({
    key: .key, 
    type: .fields.issuetype.name, 
    typeid: .fields.issuetype.id, 
    status: .fields.status.name, 
    summary: .fields.summary, 
    closedDate: .fields.resolutiondate, 
    flag: .fields.customfield_10170["value"]})'
    >  output/json/FullIssueList.json
```

I wasn't treating the entry for `flag` as a separate array. So that single line should have been:

`flag: .fields.customfield_10170[0].value`

This takes the first element in the array, `[0]` and then requests the `value` field.