# How to lift the value of a JSON object that is nested two levels deep?

Tags: json, command-line, jq, pocket

Given the following `test.json` that I received as a response from the Pocket API,

```
{
"complete": 1,
"error": null,
"list": {
    "1000055792": {
        "excerpt": "Some Text",
        "favorite": "0",
        "given_title": "Some Title",
        "given_url": "Some URL",
        "has_image": "0",
        "has_video": "0",
        "is_article": "1",
        "is_index": "0",
        "item_id": "1000055792",
        "resolved_id": "1000055792",
        "resolved_title": "Title",
        "resolved_url": "Some URL",
        "sort_id": 700,
        "status": "1",
        "time_added": "1438646514",
        "time_favorited": "0",
        "time_read": "1439025088",
        "time_updated": "1439025090",
        "word_count": "10549"
    },
    "1000102810": {
        "excerpt": "Some Text",
        "favorite": "0",
        "given_title": "Title",
        "given_url": "Some URL",
        "has_image": "1",
        "has_video": "0",
        "is_article": "1",
        "is_index": "0",
        "item_id": "1000102810",
        "resolved_id": "1000102810",
        "resolved_title": "Title",
        "resolved_url": "Resolved URL",
        "sort_id": 650,
        "status": "1",
        "time_added": "1440303789",
        "time_favorited": "0",
        "time_read": "1440320729",
        "time_updated": "1440320731",
        "word_count": "3219"
    }
```

How can I access the values of keys like `resolved_title` and `word_count`. They are nested inside an object which is a number, the same as the `id`, which in itself is nested inside `list`. I've searched and found a way to access nested objects using jq. But how can I access the values that are nested inside another object within the main `list` object?

Also, the IDs are different and not sequential, so I don't think recursion is possible, but I could be wrong. What I'm intending to do with this data is to only extract the `resolved_title` and `word_count` values for each item and save them to a two-column spreadsheet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what language are you doing this in? javascript? you added the "command-line" tag, so are you using node.js? or some other language?

Comment: @KenB The question and the tags both mention [tag:jq]

Comment: ah sorry, I thought `jq` meant jQuery, now I see it's a command line util for navigating JSON

Comment: Related / relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562424/jq-nested-object-extract-top-level-id-and-lift-a-value-from-internal-object

Comment: @tripleee Yes, I'd referred to your thread before, but the problem you had was with nested objects one level deep. I'd tried that, but it didn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The following can easily be extended and/or adapted:

```
> jq ".list[] | {resolved_title, word_count}" input.json
```

Output:

```
{
  "resolved_title": "Title",
  "word_count": "10549"
}
{
  "resolved_title": "Title",
  "word_count": "3219"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.[]` operator to iterate over all elements in an array (or in this case all the keys).  The following will give you output with each field on a separate line:

```
cat <file_with_json> | jq '.list | .[] | .resolved_title, .word_count'
```

The first filter operates on only the `list` element.  The second filter says `for every element` and finally the output is just the `resolved_title` and `.word_count` fields.  This produces the following:

```
"Title"
"3219"
"Title"
"10549"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked. You mentioned "The first filter operates on only the `list` element...". By filter, I assume you mean the `'.list` part, or am I wrong?

Comment: That's correct - `.list` is a filter that means "take the list value"

Answer (score 0):

Try `map()`:

```
$ cat myfile.json | jq '.list | map({resolved_title: .resolved_title, word_count: .word_count})'
[
  {
    "resolved_title": "Title",
    "word_count": "10549"
  },
  {
    "resolved_title": "Title",
    "word_count": "3219"
  }
]
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. A little off-topic but may I ask another question related to the command line, if you don't mind? Can I feed the output from a certain command into another command as input, without having to save the intermediate results as a file. What I mean specifically is that, can I use the command that downloads my data from Pocket and pass it onto the code you've written, using the `>` operator? Thanks again. :)

Comment: You can pipe `|` the output of Pocket to jq as long as Pocket supports sending to stdout

Comment: @AkhilUnnikrishnan yeah, any command that outputs text to the terminal can be fed into `jq` with the pipe character (`|`), and that includes any command that you use `>` for to redirect its output into a file